# C++: Is it possible to inherit the assignment operator?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following C++ code doesn't compile:

```
class BaseA {
protected:
    BaseA &operator = (const BaseA &rhs);
};

template<typename T>
class BaseB {
public:
    T &operator = (const T &rhs) {
        return *static_cast<T *>(this);
    };
};

class Derived :
    public BaseA,
    public BaseB<Derived> {
};

int main() {
    Derived foo;
    Derived bar;
    foo = bar;
    return 0;
};
```

When I try to compile this I get a complaint that `BaseA &BaseA::operator = (const BaseA &)` is undefined. There are several other questions like this on stackoverflow however they all seem to concern the compiler auto-generating a `Derived &Derived::operator = (const Derived &)` function which calls `BaseA::operator = (const BaseA&)`. In this case though `Derived` should already be inheriting a function with that exact signature from `BaseB<Derived>`. If I follow the advice on another question and add `using BaseB<Derived>::operator =;` to `Derived` the compiler complains that `Derived &operator = (const Derived &)` cannot be overloaded.

Is it simply not possible for a class to inherit this operator?

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm confused why the compiler is giving `Derived` a default `Derived &operator = (const Derived &)` when it already inherits `T &operator (const T &) where [T = Derived]` from `Base<Derived>`. I can understand why the default copy assignment operator would normally be created and override any inherited assignment operators but in this case `Derived` is inheriting an operator with *the exact same* signature as its copy assignment operator. Is there a way to write `BaseB` so that its subclasses use this operator?

Comment: I'm not sure how that error relates to your question.  You're getting that error because you declared that function, but never defined it.

Comment: The compiler is quite right that you haven't defined `BaseA& operator=` since you've only declared it. Change it to `BaseA &operator = (const BaseA &rhs) = default;` and it will happily compile.

Comment: The linker shouldn't care that it isn't defined because it should never be getting called. The only reason it would be getting called is if the compiler is generating its own Derived::operator = (const Derived &) function.

Comment: If your goal is to have `Derived's` assignment operator not call `BaseA's` assignment operator, then you are going to have to create a custom assignment operator for `Derived`.

Answer (score 5):

no, assignment operator `operator=` is not inherited.
You don't have a default

```
Derived& operator=(const BaseA& a);
```

in your Derived class.

A default assignment operator, however, is created:

```
Derived& operator=(const Derived& a);
```

and this calls the assignment operator from `BaseA`. So it's not a matter of inheriting the assignment operator, but calling it via the default generated operator in your derived class.
And some notes:
Standard says (12.8):

> An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member
>   function with exactly one parameter. Because a copy assignment
>   operator operator= is implicitly declared for a class if not declared
>   by the user (12.8), a base class assignment operator is always hidden
>   by the copy assignment operator of the derived class.

and then assignment operator of derived call your base

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union
>   class X performs memberwise copy-/move assignment of its subobjects.
>   The direct base classes of X are assigned first, in the order of their
>   declaration in the base-specifier-list, and then the immediate
>   non-static data members of X are assigned, in the order in which they
>   were declared in the class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator is one of the special member functions. If you don't provide one yourself the compiler will generate one for you by assigning the bases and then the members. If any of the base does not have an assignment operator one will be generated.

Your problem is that you have declared the assignment operator for `BaseA`, but have not provided a definition. Because it is declared, the compiler will not generate one for you, but it will try to call it to copy the `BaseA` subobject. The linker will then fail to find the definition.

Note that for the specific case of assignment, *inheriting* the base implementation does not really make sense. If that was used, as soon as one base had an assignment operator, the rest of the object would not be *assigned*. The semantics of the operation would be broken in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit base class operators and all other methods, if you not declare it in the base class - default assignment operator will be generated by compiler, if you declare it - when you have to provide you own implementation, so you are getting the error due to operator= is not defined in you BaseA class, only declared.